# Cedar - Checking that a method was called twice with different values

Tags: ios, mocking, cedar-bdd

I'm trying to verify that a method gets called twice with specific values, but I can't seem to verify both calls, just the first. I have verified that the method is called twice and that the values are correct, but I'm not sure how to write the cedar spec.

Here is what I have:

```
        it(@"should call sleep with time intervals of 0 and 5", ^{

            // subject is a spied on object
            subject should have_received(@selector(someMethod:)).with(0); // Passes
            subject should have_received(@selector(someMethod:)).with(5); // Fails
        }
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Expected <MyObject> to have received message <someMethod:>, with arguments: <5> but received messages:
  someMethod:<0>
  someMethod:<5>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're actually running into is that Cedar is very picky about types. For example, assuming `someMethod:` takes an NSTimeInterval, this is how you would fix your problem. (If it's not NSTimeInterval, replace it for the actual type).

```
    it(@"should call sleep with time intervals of 0 and 5", ^{

        // subject is a spied on object
        subject should have_received(@selector(someMethod:)).with((NSTimeInterval)0);
        subject should have_received(@selector(someMethod:)).with((NSTimeInterval)5);
    }
```

When you call `[subject someMethod:5]` the integer 5 is implicitly cast from an integer to an NSTimeInterval, but the same thing doesn't happen when you give the integer 5 to Cedar's `with()`, so Cedar does not treat them as identical. Your first assertion passed only because it's 0. If you were to change it to a non-zero value, you'd find that it fails just like the second assertion does.